# Eyes not following body

Tags: mesh, rigging, parent

I've rigged a character and added the facial rig later, however when I move it the eyes won't follow the rig nor the mesh.
The eye is a mesh and the rig is functional and the rig itself follows the body.

What would be the best way to fix this?

[image: FacialRigNotFollowing]

Comment: are the eyes meshes part of the body object? In that case select these meshes, go in the Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups, select the group they are supposed to be part of (that has the name of the bone that is supposed to control them) and click on the Assign button. If your eyes meshes are not part of the same object you can simply select them, then select the body, then ctrl J, and same operation than before.

Comment: Applied it and the mesh moves out of the position it is. 
The eyes object have a "Shrinkwrap" modifier applied to it so they curve around the head mesh.

Comment: well it's hard to understand, perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: For some reason I can't upload my file to Blender-Exchange, it give an error everytime.
Uploaded to: https://we.tl/t-X3zlfn6KS1
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: sorry I can't read your file with my version of 2.8, there's an error message, I hope someone will help   :/

Comment: Yeah I'm using the lastest one I think. Thank you eitherway :)

Comment: maybe copy paste on 2.79. About https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you need to copy paste the url of this page before uploading

Comment: Copy pasted to 2.79, noticed the hand is weird but you can focus on the eyes only. 
https://we.tl/t-ml4rHul3g0
Yup I copy pasted the URL in order to upload but for some reason still doesn't work, it let's me upload and then after a while a separate window saying "error uploading"

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the parenting: I solved the problem selecting the L eye, shift selecting the L eye rig, and pressing Ctrl P choosing "Armature deform" option (This option doesn't affect the weights you've already set). Do the same with R eye.

Then, personally, I would prefere to merge all rigs into one (Ctrl J, but you will have to rename some bones, to prevent name conflicts).

[image]